# Is emergency unloading of electric car battery viable?

Tags: resistors, lithium-ion, automotive

The massive amount of energy stored in a car battery is obviously a big problem in case of a crash. I'm wondering if it could be viable to build an emergency unloading feature that burns this energy using a resistor bank quickly.
I'm pretty sure, that this cannot be done, but I'd be glad if you could come up with a ball park number how long it might take to get rid of 50kWh using a device that could reasonably fit into a car. Let's assume we do not intend to load this battery ever again.

Comment: No matter how, the energy has to go _somewhere_. And in a lot of places, that's inevitably going to cause trouble.

Comment: Capacitors don't burn energy; they store energy.

Comment: The batteries also ignite when discharged too low.

Comment: @h0b0:  How much time are you going to allow for discharging the battery?  If you discharge it at 1000 watts, the your 50kWh battery will take 50 hours to discharge.

Comment: Put a 50kW hearer on the roof so it can discharge the battery in 1 hour...

Comment: 50 kWh is enough to launch a 100kg slug at mach 4. I'm going to argue that that's more dangerous than a battery explosion.

Comment: And as you are so safety concerned, what is done for cars carrying 10 or 15 gallons of ignitable fuel?

Comment: That's a very big battery.  I just looked at some in a car parts shop.  About 50Ah was typical and the biggest that I found was only 100th.  At 12V, even that big one is only 1.2kWh.

Comment: @badjohn, OP is talking about the battery in an electric car, not the tiny 12V battery that supplies current to the starter motor and powers accessories in a fuel-burning car. The battery in my Chevy Volt is small by electric car standards: A mere 16kWh. They say it weighs about 450 pounds, and when I mash the pedal all the way to the floor, it can supply approximately 330 A at 300 V.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Thanks.  I just noticed the lithium-ion tag.  The risk compared to the gasoline in most cars would be interesting.

Answer (score 1):

It can only go as heat, that has to be dissipated into the air rather than stored, so think fan heaters. How many 3 kW fan heaters could you array around a car, so they all blow in a safe, and different, directions? Maybe around a dozen. So that's 36 kW, or 90 minutes to dump 50 kWh.

As Dampmaskin points out in comments, it's probably a bad idea to draw this much power continuously unless the battery's cooling system is known to be working.

There are steep mountain railways, where they have a heater on the roof train to dissipate the regenerative braking energy as they come down the mountain.

Comment: Note that drawing 36 kW continuously is probably only viable if the car's own battery cooling system is still functional. Anyway, it seems pretty clear that the only practical option after a crash, is to disconnect the battery, put out any fires that could cause it to overheat, and not worry about emergency discharging. Which seems to be the common practice anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If an accident causes a an unfused short , the battery has 3 stages of thermal rise and the last is unstoppable with chemical thermal runaway.  Consider a stronger box with better thermal cooling, safe fuses, outgassing vents and don’t do anything to aggravate the situation with more heat. With a standby battery for emergency evacuation .

Comment: Equip the battery with an ejection seat?

Comment: Or a Halon system …